# PHP/JSON/ANDROID - why my JSONArray getting error

Tags: php, json

i try to displaying value of my table in android, and i put my code into hosting,
but when i try to running my app, my [link](http://www.zxccvvv.cuccfree.com/send_data.php) doesn't work,

and i tried to create new [link](http://www.mocky.io/v2/580dd704120000b70a078702) that displays the same output , and its works fine,

this is my code to encode json

`send_data.php`

```js
<?php
    include 'dbconfig.php';
    $con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $query = "select id,ask from pertanyaan";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        extract($r);
   $rows[] = array(
    "id"=>$id,
   "ask"=>$ask
      );
    }
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
     echo json_encode($rows);

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

did I'm doing something wrong??
because I want to set the output from the database

Comment: You mention an error, what error are you getting?

Comment: your links are showing this - `[{"id":"1","ask":"pertanyaan ke 1"},{"id":"2","ask":"pertanyaan ke 2"},{"id":"3","ask":"pertanyaan ke 3"},{"id":"4","ask":"pertanyaan ke 4"},{"id":"5","ask":"pertanyaan ke 5"}]`

Comment: I've tried to find an error in the [link](https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zxccvvv.cuccfree.com%2Fsend_data.php%3Fi%3D1&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices)

Comment: @mahethekiller sure, but when i try the first link, my app getting error like [this](https://postimg.org/image/g60r8gk4j/5927706a/), and it was different when I trying the 2nd link, my 2nd link work fine to display the jsonarray

Comment: i just tried your both links they both are showing same result

Comment: i think you are unable to convert it to array in your android app

Comment: but when i running out both of the link, the output is different, 
so i tried to find the problem, but nothing i got for now,
i just think my [link](http://www.zxccvvv.cuccfree.com/send_data.php) There is something wrong

Comment: you can use this in java to convert JSON to Array `JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(yourjson);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126512/discussion-between-mahethekiller-and-flix).

Comment: Bump!!

dont have any idea to solve it

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion without seeing your AJAX code:

Add this code to the top of your PHP code:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

And use this code as an example of AJAX:

```
var poutput = $('.itemsHolder');

    $.ajax({
    url: 'https://yourdomain.com/php/YOUR-PAGE.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status){

            $.each(data, function(pi,item){ 
            str = item.id;

                var products =   '<div id="'+item.id+'">'+

                                 '</div>';



              poutput.append(products);



});



},

        error: function(){
            //alert('There was an error loading the data.');
        }


});
```

Don't forget to add an element with the class name of `itemsHolder` to your page.

Comment: But sir, i've been tried another paid hosting, and its work fine, so i think my free hosting is not support JSON script, do you have another free hosting that support JSON script sir?